# C++ Boost library linker doesn't find, won't compile

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, linker, mingw

I'm trying to compile using a compiled Boost libs. I can compile using header-only Boost libraries, but now that I want to use libraries that needs to be compiled, I can't get it to work. I built the whole Boost library using toolset=gcc and --build-type=complete stage. I'm using Eclipse and I'm linking the folder at where the libs are located at: project_properties->c/c++ build->settings->mingw c++ linker->libraries and at the library search path (-L) I'm linking the folder path. I'm getting errors like:

```
undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
```

or

```
undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::lookup_default_collate_name(std::string const&)'
```

I'm compiling an example-code from the boost tutorial setup guide which includes boost/regex.hpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link your program to Boost precompiled library.

Example:

```
c++ -I path/to/boost_1_48_0 example.cpp -o example \
 -L~/boost/stage/lib/ -lboost_regex-gcc34-mt-d-1_36
```

[See description here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library)

Comment: I thought I did that? But directly in the Eclipde IDE. I have two folders at project_properties->c/c++ build->settings->mingw c++ linker->libraries (-L)

Comment: `-L` just specifies where to look for library binaries, you also need to actually link with library (`-l`)

Comment: Ok, but now I've tried to link a few different *.o from the regex directory but none works. It says: "cannot find" to all libs I'm trying to link.

Comment: @user1064036: check if you specifies path to the library correctly and  provide complete error message pls. BTW, most probably you want to link with `.a` static library, not `.o` object file.

Comment: Ok so I took out the *.a files manually to a custom folder. Now I can find all the files faster manually, is this a good choice? I can compile the regex now but if I want to compile an asio example I still get weird errors like: C:/Documents and Settings/E/Desktop/eclipse/libs/boost_1_48_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:39: undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'

Comment: Does it have to do with winsock library linking?

Comment: @user1064036: it's completely different story and would look fine as a separate question. Shortly, you should link with ws2_32.lib - WinSock2 library. Asio depends on it for platform-dependent network things.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse: project properties -> c++ build -> settings -> linker -> libraries

Add **boost_regex** to Libraries if you want to use shared library or **:/usr/lib/libboost_regex.a** (or wherever libboost_regex.a is) if you want static linking.

Comment: i get an error if i add boost_regex to libraries (cannot find -lboost_regex) I'm using windows xp btw

Comment: @user1064036: Windows or Linux doesn't matter here, but VisualC++ compiler or GCC does, because boost libraries are automatically linked using VC not-portable `#pragma comment(lib, lib-name)`. On GCC (MinGW uses it) you need to link manually.